# Javascriptedit правка текста в DOM через динамик. RegExp, проблема с изменением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть много текста в div - "[text];10;20;30" (10;20 -- случайные числа, также бывает 5;7 / 3;4 и др.) параметр - ['text'] динамический и берется из input,  значения для умножения *1го и 2го параметра также берутся из input'a

Нужно получить текст, произвести операцию , к примеру [1]*10 и [2]*15, т.е. изменить 10;20 на 100;300 ), затем вставить все это обратно в div, -> [text];100;300;30 и 10ок других подобных значений, без дублирований и замусоривания, т.е. 1ое совпадение, 2ое и т.д.

Я сделал:

```js
//func to text -> regExp
function escapeRegExp(stringToGoIntoTheRegex) {
    return stringToGoIntoTheRegex.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}


//get div text, input's
var inpTextSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave");
var fCount = document.getElementById('fCount').value ;  //10
var lCount = document.getElementById('lCount').value ;  //15
var myText = document.getElementById('myText').value; //text

var stringToGoIntoTheRegex = escapeRegExp(myText);
//with text regexp
var matching = new RegExp('\\[('+stringToGoIntoTheRegex+')\\];([0-9]{1,6});([0-9]{1,6});([0-9.0-9]{1,10})','igm');

//receive array
multiListParse = inpTextSave.innerHTML.match(matching);

//scope and all... i don't know what to do next... 
//I have 8 elements of array ([myWord];XX;YY;70)
for(var i = 0, l = multiListParse.length; i < l; i++) {

//I'm explode each element of array by ';' and the have 
//arr[0]=[myWord], arr[1]=XX, arr[2]=YY, arr[3]=70
 var explodedParse = multiListParse[i].split(';');

//then edit only XX and YY 
 explodedParse[1] = explodedParse[1]*fCount; // XX*XX2
 explodedParse[2] = explodedParse[2]*lCount; // YY*YY2
 replacement[i]=explodedParse;

//concate 4 elements to 1 string [myWord];XX*XX2;YY*YY2;70
 replacement[i]=replacement[i].join(';'); 
//it's my last test and it edit values MANY times...
 if(replacement[i].length > 0) {
  replaced = inpTextSave.innerHTML.replace(matching,replacement[i]);
 }
 else{
  return;
 }
}
//insert text to div
inpTextSave.innerHTML = replaced;
```

Comment: @Мирослав Гольтцман  Лично я не понял, что означает  [1]*10 и [2]*15, .

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow - Это номер элемента массива, после explode я получаю 4 элемента 0 - это text, 1 и 2 это числа, которые я умножаю.
Мне кажется что я выбрал вообще какой-то дальний путь и можно было решить задачу намного проще и быстрее...

Comment: @МирославГольтцман, текст вашего вопроса очень плохо читается. Если вы приведёте его в более читаемое состояние с помощью встроенного редактора, то, думаю, что вам быстрее помогут.

Comment: То есть Вы ищете более простой путь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Весь код после создания регулярного выражения заменить на этот:

```
var replacer = function() {
        return "["+arguments[1]+"];"+(arguments[2]*fCount)+";"+(arguments[3]*lCount)+";"+arguments[4];
    };
var result = inpTextSave.innerHTML.replace( matching, replacer );
```

Смысл тот же, но букв меньше.